# How to create a Facebook Application With java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook

i am new to facebook api.please can anyone help me to as to how to create a simple app .The one which i have download from [fb api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/)  are outdated.please guide. i have googled it .. but it got me no where...

Comment: IMO your best bet is to look at examples in languages FB actually supports, and try to map them to the Java API as best as possible. If you're not creating a standalone desktop app, I'd strongly consider using the official JavaScript API.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-facebook/index.html), could be what you are looking for.